# Multiple radiobutton groups with the same names?

Tags: html, radio-button, forms

Is it possible to have multiple radiobutton groups in one form with the same name values?

I'm working on a quiz which consists of multiple (questions) radiobutton groups like:

```
<div class="question">
                    <p><b>Question 19</b></p>

                    <div class="choices">

                            <input type="radio" name="choice-for-question-98" id="choice-98-1" value="389">
                            <label for="choice-98-1">e duhur </label><br>

                            <input type="radio" name="choice-for-question-98" id="choice-98-2" value="388">
                            <label for="choice-98-2">qëllim</label><br>

                            <input type="radio" name="choice-for-question-98" id="choice-98-3" value="387">
                            <label for="choice-98-3">drejt</label><br>

                            <input type="radio" name="choice-for-question-98" id="choice-98-4" value="386">
                            <label for="choice-98-4">e drejtë</label><br>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

What I want is to get a list of "answer" attributes in POST but when I set the same names for different questions, user can choose only one radiobutton from all questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The name is the mechanism used to define which group a radio button belongs to.

You could use similar, but different, names and then look for them on the server with a loop.

e.g.

```
name="choice-for-question-98-group-1"
```

and

```
my $choice;
my $group = 1;

while ($choice = $q->param("choice-for-question-98-group-" . $choice)) {
    do_something_with($choice);
    $group++;

}
```